# How to present users with multiple service options?

Tags: website-design, web-app, e-commerce, options, onboarding

We currently have a marketplace that allows users to create a project, enter specs and service providers fulfill the service.

We want to show a new option on our website which is to provide a concierge service to users. We will be in charge of reviewing & improving the project specs, choosing service providers and coordinating the logistics.

- What would be the best way to inform the user that there is the
  'concierge' service?
- Should this be done before the user enters the project creation
  funnel?
- Would a new button on the homepage/landing page saying 'premium
  service' that redirects users to information about the service be
  enough?
- What other alternatives should we consider?

**edit** Setting up the concierge service would be done after having a phone call with us. Besides informing the user about the concierge service, if the user decides to proceed, we will need to ask for their contact info. There needs to be some interaction between and the user to provide a high quality concierge service.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your platform correctly, it sounds like the concierge service is an add-on to the base services your marketplace provides. It is important to let the user know about this service early on, but you have a some options for doing so.

**Let the user know prior to creating a project**

If the concierge service is a large enough feature of its own, it might be best to let the user know about it before they spend any time creating a project. This would be especially the case if the concierge service has lengthy steps, that way the user won't have to spend extra time through the process. This also applies to your question about displaying this on the homepage, as it might need to be its own separate area.

**Let the user know as they're creating a project**

If the concierge service can be setup quickly, it might be best to include it as an option right before they create the project. That way, you can list the benefits right before the user enters the process, and it will look most advantageous at that point. Think of it as showing the user a useful accessory as they're about to purchase a product.

Comment: I forgot to mention that setting up the concierge service would be done after having a phone call with us. Besides informing the user about the concierge service, if the user decides to proceed, we will need to ask for their contact info. There needs to be some interaction between and the user to provide a high quality concierge service.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a compare type view at the beginning letting them view the details of each service before committing to filling out all their project details. this lets them see that there are two distinct routes and the pros/cons of each. It also allows you to direct users to whichever you prefer by highlighting benefits of the preferred service. Something like this poorly put together image:
[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that setting up the concierge service would be done after having a phone call with us. Besides informing the user about the concierge service, if the user decides to proceed, we will need to ask for their contact info. There needs to be some interaction between and the user to provide a high quality concierge service.

Comment: I would still say use a design pattern like the one above, then if the user decides to proceed (by choosing the concierge option) the next screen will ask for their contact input and explain when/why you need to call them.