# Is there a best practice for presenting user with options that dictate rest of the experience?

Tags: gui-design, homepage, contextual-menu, novice-users

I'm having trouble searching for the information I'm looking for because I don't know what this type of UI element/layout is known as or if it has a name at all.

I'm working on a new app for desktop that walks customers through a very specific set of trouble shooting steps for a specific product.

This is done by prompting the customer with typical yes/no style questions. However, before the user can start going through the steps they will first have to choose a general area to target: Operational, Technical, Software.

What it boils down to is that the user must choose between three options at launch, what they choose isn't really important right now, I'm curious how more experienced designers might represent that choice to the user.

Also, my current mock up has typical examples of what types of solutions might be found for each choice. This questions here is similar I believe but not exactly what I am doing, nor what I am trying to achieve. [Closest example I could find](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80560/how-to-present-users-with-multiple-service-options)

Here's what I'm curious about:

- How would an experienced designer handle this?
- How best to convey what each of the three "paths" cover while still adhering to a material design UI stle
- When designing UI for technical software in which the users of said software have a wide range of experience levels with the product, are there any best practices to be aware of? Good examples of this kind of design focus?

Comment: For general on-boarding you could try http://www.useronboard.com/. For more specific product selection examples, you could try looking at PC hardware driver installations; quite often these require the user to select their exact product by selecting the class, family, and product in a triage process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they select this option only once? Or do they need to select that every time before doing a particular task? This is very important to know.

Either way, the 3 options sound distinct enough for the user types I believe you'll be dealing with.

If you need to give more context to the options, and users need to select only one option that matches their "profile"/"field", I'd create 3 fictitious characters, give them a name and a small story about each of them. And let users choose the option (illustrated by the characters) that better match their needs.